# Vert-x RxJava Map implementation of Single not match with HttpResponse::body argument

Tags: vert.x, reactive

Hi I'm currently into vertx rxjava and I found I can figure out why the interface below can be implemented with HttpResponse.body.

This is the usage of the map interface

```
Single<JsonObject> s1 = request1.rxSend().map(HttpResponse::body);
```

If we see the map implementation of Single is

```
public final <R> Single<R> map(Func1<? super T, ? extends R> func)
```

which Func1 is a functional interface with detail below

```
public interface Func1<T, R> extends Function {
    R call(T t);
}
```

The interface allow a method which accept 1 input argument, and return a value type R. While the HttpResponse.Body implementation detail is below

```
public T body() { 
    if (cached_6 != null) {
      return cached_6;
    }
    T ret = (T)__typeArg_0.wrap(delegate.body());
    cached_6 = ret;
    return ret;
  }
```

As we can see the implementation accept no argument and return a value. Why its compatible with map interface? Please enlighten me. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. When I tried to change method reference into lambda, I cleary the reason why. rxSend output is Single. Therefore the map will iterate/execute with HttpResponse object inside it. Silly question, onwards!